# Link to external website doesn't work properly inside article tag

Tags: html

I am using the following template from html5up to create a personal website:

http://html5up.net/strata

In the recent work section section for the description under the thumbnail of each project picture I want to add links to the project url and the github url.

When I try to add anchor tags with those links inside the article tag the link starts to open a lightbox window that loads infinitely and I get this error:

```
"Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:"
```

Here's some sample code of what I'm trying to do:

```
<h2>Recent Work</h2>
                    <div class="row">
                        <article class="6u 12u$(xsmall) work-item">
                            <a href="images/fulls/project.png" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs/project.png" alt="" /></a>
                            <h3>Project Title</h3>
                            <p>Project description<a href="http://html5up.net/strata">link</a></p>
                        </article>
```

I want to put links in the p tag with the project's description, but I get errors while doing so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `init.js` file, you'll find this code:

```
// Lightbox gallery.
$('#two').poptrox({
    caption: function($a) { return $a.next('h3').text(); },
    overlayColor: '#2c2c2c',
    overlayOpacity: 0.85,
    popupCloserText: '',
    popupLoaderText: '',
    selector: '.work-item a',
    usePopupCaption: true,
    usePopupDefaultStyling: false,
    usePopupEasyClose: false,
    usePopupNav: true,
    windowMargin: (skel.isActive('small') ? 0 : 50)
});
```

Change the `selector: '.work-item a',` to `selector: '.work-item a.image',`

This will make the Lightbox work only on links with the `image` class, and not try to work on all links inside the `work-item` article.